# Create HyperLink in dynamic pdf using iText in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I created a pdf dynamically, now I want to add the link in the pdf. Is it possible?

If so, and if you have any idea, than please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try,below article link for explains for adding anchor in itext pdf

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/anchor.html

and sample code from above article on link

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

    public class AnchorExample {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document document = new Document();

        try {
          PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("Anchor.pdf"));

          document.open();

          Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
          paragraph.add(new Phrase("You can find the IText tutorial at "));


          Anchor anchor = new Anchor(
              "http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html");
          anchor.setReference(
              "http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html");

          paragraph.add(anchor);

          document.add(paragraph);

          document.close();

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank u for this, but when i am trying this code           Anchor anchor_mobileapp = new Anchor("App link");
          anchor_mobileapp.setReference("mycoolapp://");  this code is not working in android mobile (adobe reader mobile app). your code is working fine.

Comment: Hi all, Do you have any solution for this or not  ?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

document is the PDF File which you are creating.

```
        var chunk=Chunk("Text To be Displayed: CodingKaro.in")
        chunk.setAnchor("https://www.codingkaro.in/")
        document.add(chunk)
```